# How to update View Model through Dependency Service in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Froms project that consumes a Scanner class from Android Native Libraries, therefore, I had to create a dependency service to use the scanner like this:

```
Solution
 |- Forms.App
 |   |- App.cs
 |   |- MyViewPage.xaml
 |   |- MyViewModel.cs
 |   |- IScanService.cs
 |   | ...
 |   
 |- Droid Project
 |   |- ScanService.cs
 |   |- Scanner.cs
 |   | ...
```

I'm already able to consume my ScanService from Xamarin Forms app, however this service sets a timer and starts some parallel loop task waiting for scanner to find stuff, now I need to update my View Model on the fly to see results at the UI Page, here some example classes:

View Model Class:

```
class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IScanService scanService;
    private ObservableCollection<string> scannerResultList;

    public int ScannerResultList
    {
        get { return this.scannerResultList; }
        set { SetValue(ref this.scannerResultList, value); }
    }

    public IScanService ScanService
    {
        get { return this.scanService; }
        set { SetValue(ref this.scanService, value); }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.ScanService = DependencyService.Get<IScanService>();
        this.ScannerResultList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
```

Dependency Service Interface:

```
public interface IScanService
{
    public bool IsConnected();

    void Scan();

    void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);

    void CancelScan();

}
```

Scan Service Class

```
public class ScanService : IScanService
{
    public static List<string> scannerResultList;
    public static Scanner myScanner;

    public ScanService()
    {
         scannerResultList = new List<string>();
         myScanner = new Scanner();
    }

    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        //Return scanner connection
    }

    public void Scan()
    {
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 100;
            _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed(sender, e);
            _timer.Start();
        };
    }

    public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    { 
       if(myScanner.NewEvent()){
           scannerResultList.Add(myScanner.Event());
       }
    }

    public void CancelScan()
    {
    //Some stuff here
    }
}
```

Now my problem is I need to update my ObservableList while scanning, how can I achieve it?

Comment: your service can raise a custom event whenever it needs to notify the VM of a change, or you could use MessagingCenter to pass a message from the Service to the VM

Comment: Thanks for your response Jason, do you have some brief example or documentation on how can I do that?

Comment: custom events are a basic C# concept and are well documented.  MessagingCenter is well documented in the official Xamarin docs

Comment: you could also pass an action as an argument to Scan() that will be called whenever a scan completes

Comment: MessagingCenter works fine, thanks buddy.